how to make screen in React Native and use Javascript in which we have Grid of 4x4 dice which gets from list and 4 player profile
Can any one make that screen in React Native . In which there  is Grid of 4x4 dice which get from list .
Also 4 Player who is playing that game  , and also spectator (Viewer) can comment on the screen . I
I expected to get the screen below
enter image description here

Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Answering your question - sure, someone can do that assignment. But stackoverflow is not a free coding service. If you have a specific coding problem, please specify.
